# Java: how do I make JSpinner show value with some offset

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

In my application some values internally have their range from 0. But user should see this range starting from 1. I thought it would be appropriate to move this offseting stuff into presentation. In this case it is JSpinner component. So that I could specify in contructor if there is an offset (not all values have it). But if I override `getValue()` of JSpinner or `getValue()` of model to be something like that (+1 is just for test)

```
       public Object getValue() {
            Number value = (Number)super.getValue();
            Number newValue=value;
            if (value instanceof Double){
                newValue=value.doubleValue()+1;
            }
            else if (value instanceof Integer){
                newValue = value.intValue()+1;
            }
            return newValue;
        }
```

it goes into infinite loop. I guess, it fires state change event for some reason here. Calls `getValue` again, increments more, fires event, increments and so on.
How could this be solved? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mingle your program's data model and the spinner's number model; keep them separate. Delegate to a private `SpinnerNumberModel` having the correct presentation range, 1..*n*. Provide an accessor that returns values in the desired range, 0..*n*–1.

> Provide the method `getAdjustedValue()`, which is basically `getValue()-offset`, that all clients should use instead of `getValue()`?

Yes. The `SpinnerModel` serves the `JSpinner` view. If your application's model uses different units, some transformation must occur. You'll have to decide where that makes most sense. As a concrete example, this [model](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel)'s [`ControlPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel/code#ControlPanel) has a spinner that adjusts a frequency in *Hz*, while the application's `Timer` requires a period in milliseconds.

Comment: So, if there is an offset, JSpinner passes `value+offset` to `SpinnerNumberModel` and provides method `getAdjustedValue` which is basically `getValue()-offset`, which all clients should use instead of `getValue`? Did I understand you correct?

Answer (score 2):

I think that [CyclingSpinnerListModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SpinnerDemoProject/src/components/CyclingSpinnerListModel.java) can do that

Comment: Could you elaborate that? I don't see how it helps

Comment: @Boris Mikhaylov that about `it goes into infinite loop.`, then you can restict that into some Range

Comment: +1 This is a good example of a private `SpinnerModel`, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921689/java-how-do-i-make-jspinner-show-value-with-some-offset/7924274#7924274).